# ReactJs: How to add/append a component on click of button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Say `<componentX \>` when onClick of "create box" button, the componentX should append inside of box-container. If i click create box 3 times, then three componentX should append inside box-container (It's not that simply keeping the component then hide and show when click of create box). What are all the ways to achieve this in ReactJS.

```js
import ComponentX from './ComponentX.jsx';

class App extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
  super();
  
  this.state = {

  }
 }

 render(){
  let board = Box;

  return(
   <div>   
    <a onClick={}>Create Box</a>
    <div className="box-container"></div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import ComponentX from './ComponentX.jsx';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            children: [];
        }
    }

    appendChild(){
        this.setState({
            children: [
                ...children,
                <componentX \>
            ]
        });
    }

    render(){
        let board = Box;

        return(
            <div>   
                <a onClick={() => this.appendChild()}>Create Box</a>
                <div className="box-container">
                    {this.state.children.map(child => child)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render by using component state like this:

---

```
import ComponentX from './ComponentX.jsx';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
          showComp = false;
        }
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({
           showComp: true,
       })
    }

    render(){
        let board = Box;
        const { showComp } = this.state;

        return(
            <div>   
                <a onClick={this.handleClick}>Create Box</a>
                <div className="box-container">
                  {showComp && <ComponentX />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```